# sqlalchemy inner join

Tags: sql, sqlalchemy, inner-join, inner

Помогите, пожалуйста, написать в sqlalchemy запрос.
Цель перемножить таблицу на саму себя.
Запрос следующий:

```
select PA1.symbol, PA1.price_usd as Price1, PA1.date_of_download as Date1, PA2.price_usd as Price2, PA2.date_of_download as Date2 from
        [crypto2].[dbo].[Coinmarketcap] as PA2
        inner join [crypto2].[dbo].[Coinmarketcap]  as PA1
on      PA1.Symbol = PA2.Symbol
        and PA2.[date_of_download] > PA1.[date_of_download]
        and PA1.[price_usd] <> PA2.[price_usd]
        and PA1.[price_usd] <> 0
        and PA2.[price_usd] <> 0
```